# TermsLookup without docID

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

Can we do a term lookup in between different indexes, without doc id? I have implemented this in the console :

It is working if you provide a document id. This is the query.

```
GET /tweets/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "user" : {
                "index" : "users",
                "type" : "_doc",
                "id" : "2",
                "path" : "followers"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to do this, without being aware of document id in which I need to do the lookup. I want to get a list of values for a field, from all documents from another index.

Comment: Technically, that is what your query is doing. `Give me all the tweets which contains any of the followers from users index - id 2`. whats your exact problem statement

Comment: Give me all the tweets which contains any of the followers from users index